# Fill 2 Form Input Fields With 1 Hyperlink Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, hyperlink, click, fill

I'm sorry if this has been answered somewhere as it's quite a simple issue but I can't seem to find anything which is completely relevant and I'm very new to coding and javascript.

I have a form like this:

```
<form name="myform" method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="word" id="word" value="" />
<input type="text" name="url" id="url" value="" /> 
</form>
```

and I'm currently using some inline javascript on a hyperlink to fill the 'word' input with a database value like this (this is within a php function):

```
<a id="fill" href="#" onclick="document.myform.word.value=  &apos;'. $aMessages['name'] .'&apos; ">fill form</a>
```

However I also want this hyperlink to fill the 'url' input with a different database value which would be with this javascript:

```
onclick="document.myform.url.value=  &apos;'. $aMessages['url'] .'&apos;
```

but I'm not sure how to make that one hyperlink fill both form inputs at the same time. If this is the wrong way of achieving what I want and there is another better way to do this then please let me know.

Thank you for your time!

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write two javascript codes in one onclick.
Like:

```
<a id="fill" href="#" onclick="javascript:document.myform.word.value=  &apos;'. $aMessages['name'] .'&apos; document.myform.url.value=  &apos;'. $aMessages['url'] .'&apos;">fill form</a>
```

**But I'd recommend doing it this way:**

```
function doUpdate()
{
document.myform.word.value=  "'. $aMessages['name'] .'";
document.myform.url.value=  "'. $aMessages['url'] .'";
}
```

And on your  link do this:

```
<a id="fill" href="#" onclick="javascript:doUpdate()">fill form</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the ';' to separate the sentences

```
<?php 
$a = "<a id='fill' href='#' onclick='document.myform.word.value='" . $aMessages['name'] . "';document.myform.url.value‌​‌​=" . $aMessages['name'] . ">fill form</a>"; echo $a; 
?>
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much. I actually tried this but it didn't work the first time for some reason. Tried it again and voila. Thanks again.

Comment: `document.myform.word.value=  '. $aMessages['name'] .';` ?? Seriously? Assigning a string without any quotes around it?

Comment: Sry, I changed the comment

Comment: Try it out, the PHP Code would still not compile. Seriously.

Comment: `$a = '<a id="fill" href="#" 
onclick="document.myform.word.value=$aMessages['name'];document.myform.url.value=   $aMessages['name'] ">fill form</a>';` -> unexpected 'name' (T_STRING)

Comment: `$a = "<a id="fill" href="#" onclick="document.myform.word.value=$aMessages['name'];document.myform.url.value‌​= $aMessages['name'] ">fill form</a>";` -> unexpected 'fill' (T_STRING)

Comment: <?php
$a = "<a id='fill' href='#' onclick='document.myform.word.value='" . $aMessages['name'] . "';document.myform.url.value‌​‌​=" . $aMessages['name'] . ">fill form</a>";
echo $a;
?>

Comment: Exactly, so you need to change your answer accordingly. Removed the downvote! *Thumbs Up*

Comment: Ok, I changed the comment again